# Android Image zooming animation

Tags: android

I'm doing an android application which has image zooming animation control with start & stop buttons.(i.e)I've two buttons with an image.when i click start,the image should do zooming animation.when i click stop,it should stop animation.,and again if i click start,it should resume zooming from the stopped position.How could i do that?
 Below is my working sample code:

ImageView imageView;
    ScaleAnimation zoom;
    Animation animset;
    float gg;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    zoom = new ScaleAnimation(0, 1, 0, 1);
    zoom.setDuration(3000);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.startAnimation(zoom);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.start)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.stop)).setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.start:
        zoom.setDuration((long) gg);
        zoom.start();

        break;
    case R.id.stop:
        gg = zoom.getDuration();
        break;

    }

}
```

}
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

**ZoomInActivity.java**

```
    public class ZoomInActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
    
        ImageView imgPoster;
        Button btnStart;
    
        // Animation
        Animation animZoomIn;
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom_in);
    
            imgPoster = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
            btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    
            // load the animation
            animZoomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.zoom_in);
            
            // set animation listener
            animZoomIn.setAnimationListener(this);
    
            // button click event
            btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // start the animation
                    imgPoster.startAnimation(animZoomIn);
                }
            });
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // Take any action after completing the animation
    
            // check for zoom in animation
            if (animation == animZoomIn) {          
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        }
    
    }
```

**activity_zoom_in.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center">
        
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/man_of_steel"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Animation"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
        
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Make `anim` folder in `res` and create `zoom_in.xml`

**zoom_in.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fillAfter="true" >
    
        <scale
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromXScale="1"
            android:fromYScale="1"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toXScale="3"
            android:toYScale="3" >
        </scale>
    
    </set>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Im ok.But i need to stop & resume zooming at the stopped position.How could i do that

Comment: how can we zoom out from same image?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But after zoomout how to gone the imageview

Comment: Hi RINK, Please help me on this like in the Image - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62756897/android-smooth-animation-not-coming-fine

Answer (score 1):

Easy and Simple

- Create folder res/anim
- Put animation descriptions into res/anim folder
- Set animation to image using below code

  ```
  ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageId);
  image.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.zoom_in_anim));
  ```